# Asterisk: ignore call forwarding in queue

Tags: forwarding, asterisk, queue

Scenario: there is a simple queue configured for 3 extensions (1, 2, 3). User of the phone 1 enabled call forwarding on his phone (let's say, to extension 10).

Problem: if a call comes in, it directly goes to 10, but I would like Asterisk to ignore 1 and its forwarding to 10, and continue queue processing using extensions 2 and 3.

In other words, only the currently 'active' phones should participate in the queue. When forwarding is disabled on phone 1, it should be back into the queue members.

Is it possible?

```
# extensions.conf
same => n,Queue(qname)

# queues.conf
[qname]
member => Local/1@ctx/n,0,Phone1,SIP/1
member => Local/2@ctx/n,0,Phone2,SIP/2
member => Local/3@ctx/n,0,Phone3,SIP/3
```

Answer (score 0):

If user enabled CF on PHONE it is not possible, unless you have phone which inform somehow about CF.

If CF enabled via FreePBX dialplan, you can check state via ASTDB.